# How to show a CSV file as a link and download it on click in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, csv, download

I am working on a React Native app where I need the user to fill in a template and upload it to the system for importing data. The template csv file is in my assets folder. Now I need to show the template file as a link and on clicking that, it should download the file to the user's device. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Files in assets folder are already on users device as soon as your app is installed.

Comment: No its not available in the assets folder

Comment: ???? You said: `The template csv file is in my assets folder.`

Comment: It's in my assets folder while in dev mode, but once an apk is created it's not there in actual device, that's what I meant.

Comment: The idea behind the whole assets folder is that you can put files there at design time to use them at runtime. So they are there on your device to be used. Seems only you dont know how and looked at the wrong place. Where did you look exactly?